# instruments (Leaks) not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my Xcode 4.0 IOS 4.3 instruments not working when checking leaks on device.It works fine with simulator.I tried reinstalling my Xcode.It doesn't show anything when i choose targets in the instrument.Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is not working"... more details might be helpful.

Comment: if possible can you put some explonation or error message or any response

Comment: When i am checking the leaks in the simulator, instrument works fine but when i am checking the leaks in device instrument is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try selecting the target from the top bar;(Next to the Record, restart button)
After connecting the device, it should show choose target.
Try choosing your target from there.

Comment: Might be this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297554/instruments-does-not-work-on-xcode-4-with-device