# Can't "Profile" app on device using instruments in xcode. Record button greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, instruments

The record button is greyed out when I try to profile my app on the device using instruments. In the simulator it works fine but when I launch Instruments using Product -> Profile, Instruments launches successfully but the record button is greyed out. My Scheme is set to Debug. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that your 'Target' (iOS Simulator etc) and Scheme (SampleApp.app etc.) are set properly? If yes, which Xcode version are you using. Please share a screenshot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instruments does not work on XCode 4 with device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297554/instruments-does-not-work-on-xcode-4-with-device)